# Microsoft Word 2008 on the Mac sometimes "Disappears" documents, really

Tags: microsoft-word-2008

This happens in a computer lab environment, has happened at least 3 times.  We are running Microsoft Office 2008 for mac on Leopard, everything is updated.  Our user's home directories are on a network drive, but the /Library/Cache folder is running locally.

Typically a student will have a Word file that they have been working on, it's been saved before they even logged onto the computer that day.  They log on, open the document, click the save icon (not go to File > Save), sometimes even save multiple times, then close Word.  The document is now gone.

It's not hidden, there are no autosaves or anything in the Cache folder.  Definitely not in the trash or trashes folder.  It can't find it when you click on it in 'recent documents'.  Searching meticulously though every folder in their home drive turns up nothing.  They look using Finder, I look ssh'd as root into their home using ls -la.  I look for similar files in case they renamed it by mistake.  It's gone.  Disappeared.  Vaporized.

It's happened to at least 3 different users in the past year.  Much whining.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm you are running 12.2.4?

This is may be caused by a missing `.TemporaryItems` directory at the root of the share on the server. Alternatively it can occur if they don't have the proper permissions to use that directory (my hunch is it's this).

Apple actually has a KBase article on this: [Microsoft Office applications fail to save to a server volume](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA23804?viewlocale=en_US), but the error is usually to do with that it can't save instead of silently deleting the file.

Comment: I can't confirm if this has fixed it, but it looks promising as these directories are missing.

Comment: the issue has gone away, kudos